# Hypersurface of complex projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Is there example of hypersurface $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ satisfying

1. $X$ is of degree 2. (I mean, the Poincare dual PD(X) is 2u, where u is a generator of
   $H^2(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathbb{Z})$.
2. Some odd betti number is non-zero.

Thank you for any comment.

Comment: All quadrics are cellular. In particular, it implies all odd Betti numbers are zero.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As noticed by Sasha in his comment, the answer is **no**.

The following proof also shows that this result cannot be generalized for higher values of the degree.

For any smooth complex hypersurface of degree $d$, say $X_d \subset \mathbb{P}^{n+1}$, by standard arguments involving Lefschetz theorem we have $$H^k(X_d)= H^k(\mathbb{P}^n) \quad  \mathrm{for} \; k \neq n.$$

In particular, all the odd Betti numbers are zero, except possibly the middle Betti number 
when $n$ is odd. On the other hand, the Euler-Poincare characteristic of $X_d$ is equal to $$\chi(X_d)= \langle c_n(T_{X_d}), [X_d] \rangle =\frac{1}{d}[(1-d)^{n+2}-1]+n+2,$$
so for $n$ odd and $d=2$ the middle cohomology group must be zero too. Notice that for $n$ odd and $d >2$ one always has a non-zero middle Betti number. For instence, if $X \subset \mathbb{P}^4$ is a smooth cubic hypersurface, then $b_3(X)=10$.

A good reference for these results is Dimca's book *Singularities and topology of hypersurfaces*, Chapter 5, which also considers the case of hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ with isolated singularities.

Comment: I don't know whether the question was meant to include non-smooth quadric hypersurfaces, but the answer is the same for them: their (co)homology is free and concentrated in even degrees. In fact, every singular quadric $X$ in $\mathbb P^{n+1}$ is the projective cone on some quadric $Y$ in $\mathbb P^{n}$, making $H_k(X)$ isomorphic to $H_{k-2}(Y)$ for every $k>0$.

Comment: Yes, that's true. However, I find this proof interesting since its provides the Betti numbers for hypersurfaces of any degree d, not only for quadrics, showing that in higher degrees, when n is odd,  one always has a non-zero odd Betti number. I have edited the answer to make this more clear.