# Complex manifolds with the same cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, cohomology, hodge-theory

Is there an example of two **non-homeomorphic** projective smooth complex varieties $X$ and $Y$ such that there exists an isomorphism $H^{\ast}(X,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow H^{\ast}(Y,\mathbb{C})$ of commutative-graded algebras compatible with Hodge filtration.

Thank you all for your very nice comments, it is helpful. I want to add a question with slightly different hypothesis.

**second question:**
Suppose we have a holomorphic map $f:Y\rightarrow X$ between two smooth projective complex varieties such that the induced map $H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H^{\ast}(Y;\mathbb{Q})$ is an isomorphism. Is it true that $f$ is an isomorphism ?

Comment: Isn't that already true for $X$ equal to $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $Y$ equal to a smooth quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^4$?

Comment: Here is a copy of a paper http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM2010.1/Main/icm2010.1.0476.0503.pdf See if it might be helpful to you in some way; in particular page 496.

Comment: Professor @JasonStarr I just noticed your comment! Could you please give more details about $Y$ in your example. It will be nice if there is such example in "low" dimension.

Comment: Please refer to the following MathOverflow answer by Francesco Polizzi  to see that for $n$ odd, both linear and quadratic hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ have equal Betti numbers.  Moreover, the Hodge filtration on each is trivial.  Finally, since you are working with $\mathbb{C}$-coefficients rather than something smaller, the cup product algebra structures are also trivial.  MO link: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42038/hypersurface-of-complex-projective-space

Comment: @NguyenlanLee moreover you cannot extend this example in lower dimension. If $Q$ is a smooth quadric in $\mathbb{P}^3$ then $H^2(Q) \cong \mathbb{C}^2$, where a smooth plane quadric is of course isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: In dimension $2$, one can take $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ and $\mathbb P^2$ blown up at a point. They are not homeomorphic because the cup product pairing on $H^2$ is even on the first but not even on the second, but they have the same cohomology algebras because those pairings become isomorphic after tensoring with $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Regarding your second question, let $Y$ be a smooth quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb{CP}^4$, let $X$ be $\mathbb{CP}^3$, and let $f:Y\to X$ be a linear projection of degree $2$.  The pullback ring homomorphism $f^*:H^*(X^{\text{an}};\mathbb{Z})\to H^*(Y^{\text{an}};\mathbb{Z})$ is not an isomorphism, but the pullback ring homomorphism $f^*:H^*(X^{\text{an}};\mathbb{Q})\to H^*(Y^{\text{an}};\mathbb{Q})$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you for the explanation, I think I start to understand now what is going on.